# Being new, how can I make sure my answers are given due attention?

Tags: discussion, new-users

What if even after posting the right solution/answer, I do not get an up vote?

Please let me know if there is anything I can do.

Comment: Is it the *best* answer? Can't you make it *better*?

Comment: I've edited one of your answers to format code as... code.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: I think it is too early to ask this question. You can spend a few weeks and see other well-received answers. You will learn it naturally.

Comment: Making sure your stuff is formatted correctly is a big one.  Definitely review the edits on your answers to learn how to format your answers well.  Although, I might not have gone with so much **emphasis**; be sparing `in` *your* ***formatting***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the site, it's a matter of knowing your audience. I've been experimenting with posting with a secondary account once or twice.

*Know your audience* - make your answers *clear* and *interesting*. Depending on the site, there's other tricks - I use screenshots (static of GIF based). Format things for *maximum clarity* and there's a good chance your answers will be better received.

Answer (score 13):

Your answer makes the question bump on the frontpage again. That means it will get eyes from some users. That doesn't mean they immediately upvote your post.

Maybe it was okay(ish), maybe not. You can try to **improve your post** until you think it is perfect. Format code as code, write in clear English and divide your posts into paragraphs. Maybe the question can be improved so it stands out. Then you just have to wait. Maybe it will eventually gain some votes.

Also make sure you answer questions that are on-topic. One of your posts is an answer to a tutorial request. We don't like those questions.

Answer (score 7):

Just be patient. You only have [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414315/nikhil-jagtiani) that's more than an hour old. As a new user, your first post (question or answer) is reviewed automatically, so it will get extra attention. After that, it doesn't matter for the visibility of your answer whether you have 10, 1000 or 100,000 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to bear in mind is not to waste your time on bad questions. Learn about what are acceptable questions on Stack Overflow and concentrate your effort on questions which have themselves used some effort.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736523/mean-stack-2-implementation/39768929#39768929) for example was probably not worth your time.